# How do I clone a class in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a scala project in intellij. I would like to clone a new class into the same package the source class is in, but I cant figure out how to do this. I can see how to copy it to a new package, but I want to copy/clone within the same package.

[Edit]

If I have a class called orderwidget in package com.company.widgets and I want to create productwidget in com.company.widgets, I need to be able to clone orderwidget and rename it. Copy wont work because orderwidget already exists in the package.

Comment: with Java classes at least (but I guess it's the same in Scala): F5 (or Refactor - Copy...)

Comment: no copy wont work in the same package.

Comment: If you do Refactor -> Copy it lets you rename the file. So why is this not working?

Comment: Ah. The problem I am having is when the file orderwidget.scala has an object AND a class in it. I can clone one, or the other, but not both. If I select the file then I dont get the clone option, but if I select either the class or the object I get the clone option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I use is drag & drop the file you try to copy to the parent folder in Project view, holding `Ctrl` to copy the file.

I admit it works in some cases but doesn't in others. Sometimes Idea offers you a dialog asking for name of the new file; sometimes is doesn't and gives "File already exists" error; sometimes it copies the file but messes up it's contents (Idea 14.1.4)