# How to copy a scala source file to same directory (with different name) from Intellij explorer

Tags: intellij-idea

From the screenshot below:  I did a `command-C` copy of a scala source file - seen in the screenshot as `BpmSpecs` . Then went to the containing folder `eventapi` , right clicked and selected `paste`.

Well .. Intellij did a rather boneheaded thing here: it created a new **directory** called .. wait for it .. `LocalEngineCycles.scala` .. and proceeded to copy the original file into that directory under the same name as the original file.

[image]

So .. how to copy a scala source file into the same directory - and having intelllij actually *help* us by allowing us to supply the new filename ?

Re: **possible duplicate**: it is *not*. This problem relates to a File. I clone classes successfully all the time: IJ asks me to change the ClassName and I do it. For the file it gets confused and instead creates a new directory and places a copy of the original file inside this new directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a class in intellij?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534814/how-do-i-clone-a-class-in-intellij)

Comment: @AndriiAbramov  No, this problem relates to a *File*.  I clone classes successfully all the time: IJ asks me to change the ClassName and I do it. For the file it gets confused and instead creates a new directory and places a copy of the original file inside this new directory.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. Can you provide more details why this issue is different to the provided one?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I do not understand your question.  I can copy classes. I can not copy a file.